# Как исправить ошибку cors в Golang?

Tags: api, golang, frontend, backend, cors

Необходимо на сервере каким-то образом отключить cors политику, чтобы я с localhost:4200 мог достучаться на сервер, чтобы получить данные.

Запрос на фронте:

```
console.log(this.http.get('localhost:8080/videocard/2').pipe(
      map(
        data => {
          console.log(data);
          return [];
        })));
    return {} as any;
```

Я хочу внутри остановиться и увидеть какой-нибудь результат

На беке

```
r := mux.NewRouter()
r.HandleFunc("/videocard/2", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.Write([]byte("{\"hello\": \"world\"}"))
})

// Use default options
handler := cors.Default().Handler(r)
http.ListenAndServe(":8080", handler)
```

Использую пакет "github.com/rs/cors"

Перепробовал много всего, но что-то делаю не так и ни разу не смогу с фронта получить запрос. Отключал корсы в сафари, тоже ничего не помогает.

Comment: если добавить `w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*") Поможет?`

Comment: @Kers не помогает, расширял до всевозможных заголовком. Он даже в хендлер не заходит дебатам

Comment: Посмотрите как пример `https://github.com/rs/cors`, кажется в пользовался этим (давно правда было дело) но может будет полезно.

Comment: @Kers по нему и делал, несколько раз, увы

Comment: Отключить CORS на сервере это не совсем то что поможет. Поскольку по логике если сервер не ответит как надо на запрос (options) от браузера то основной запрос не пойдет как надо. 

К вопросу о localhost:8080. Мне кажется что сервер запущен под каким-то IP а не localhost

Comment: @AzizUmarov может знаете решение как обойти данную проблему? я дописывал и  ip и localhost - 0 результат.

Comment: @Lancelot https://pastebin.com/QTtY1hHc а такое вы пробовали?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
r.HandleFunc("/videocard/2", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, PATCH")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Accept, Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization")
    w.Write([]byte("{\"hello\": \"world\"}"))
})
```

Можете добавить код ошибки с фронта?